# ckeditor gem custom config.js not loading in production

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ckeditor

I followed the instructions on the gem readme to use ckeditor on my rails app but once I try to use it on the production environment with heroku, the config.js file that is used is from the CDN link and not from my assets/javascripts/ckeditor/config.js file. The custom config works in the development environment.

ckeditor.rb
initializers/assets/application.rb

```
Rails.application.config.assets.version = '1.0'
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( ckeditor/*)
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( custom_styling.css )
```

initializers/assets/ckeditor.rb

```
    Ckeditor.setup do |config|
      require 'ckeditor/orm/active_record'

       config.image_file_types = %w(jpg jpeg png gif tiff)

       config.attachment_file_types = %w(mp4 doc docx xls odt ods pdf rar zip tar tar.gz swf)

       config.cdn_url = "//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.11.3/standard/ckeditor.js"

       config.js_config_url = 'ckeditor/config.js'
    end
```

assets/javascripts/ckeditor/config.js

```
    CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
      config.language = 'en';
      config.uiColor = '#ffffff';

      config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";
      config.filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";
      config.filebrowserFlashUploadUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";
      config.filebrowserImageBrowseLinkUrl = "/ckeditor/pictures";
      config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = "/ckeditor/pictures";
      config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = "/ckeditor/pictures?";
      config.filebrowserUploadUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";
      config.allowedContent = true;

      config.toolbar = [
        { name: 'document', groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ], items: [ 'Source'] },
        { name: 'clipboard', groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ], items: [ 'Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo' ] },
        { name: 'links', items: [ 'Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor' ] },
        { name: 'insert', items: [ 'Image', 'Flash', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'SpecialChar' ] },

      ];
    };
```

config/initializers/assets.rb

```
Rails.application.config.assets.version = '1.0'
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( ckeditor/config.js)
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( custom_styling.css )
```

views/article_templates/edit_form.html.erb

```
<%= javascript_include_tag Ckeditor.cdn_url %>
<textarea id="content" name="content" class="ckeditor"><%= raw @article.content %></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should set the correct path for the `config.js` in the `ckeditor.rb`:

`config.js_config_url = "/assets/ckeditor/config.js"`

But is useless because is the default path

```
  # JS config url
  # Used when CKEditor CDN enabled
  # By default: "/assets/ckeditor/config.js"
  # config.js_config_url = "/assets/ckeditor/config.js"
```

Also you should change the assets precompilation in this way:

`Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w(ckeditor/config.js)`

Comment: Thanks. I tried your suggestions and it still uses the config.js file from the CDN "//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.11.3/standard/ckeditor.js". I also tried the '/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/config.js' and still get no change in the production app.

Comment: what version of Rails are you using?

Comment: I'm using rails 5.1.6.

Comment: Can you share all the assets.rb?

Comment: Remove this line: `config.cdn_url = "//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.11.3/standard/ckeditor.js"`

Comment: Thanks for following up. I tried removing the cdn_url definition but it just causes an error on the production html page that uses the link. In my development environment it works without it likely because it is using files from the gem installation and my custom config.js file. I currently have <script> javascript_include_tag Ckeditor.cdn_url </script>at the top of the HTML pages with ckeditor per the ckeditor gem readme. I think the gem files are definitely not being used in the production environment somehow.